# Consuming WCF web service from Android application

Tags: android, wcf, web-services

I want to consume WCF web service from Android application. I have worked on .asmx web service but I don't know how to consume a SCF web service in Android application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is an article explaining how to consume web service with android in general](http://romenlaw.blogspot.com/2008/08/consuming-web-services-from-android.html)

There are a couple of particulars when it comes to WCF and being interoperable with java you want to be careful about. [This article series explains a great deal about it.](http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop)