# How to connect localhost ASP.net WCF service with android mobile?

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, ip

I tried different IP address and port number but unable  to establish connection from mobile to pc network.

I disabled firewall also. Want to see the web service running in the pc should view in mobile.

```
http://10.0.2.2:63114/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsont/k1234
```

Comment: Try running the web service on port 80 and using a web debugging proxy like Charles: http://www.charlesproxy.com/ - then you can start to examine the requests and diagnose what is going wrong

Comment: Note: You cannot run the web service on the same machine as charles, from my experience anyway never seems to work

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213115/consuming-wcf-web-service-from-android-application

Comment: i'am able to connectservice with emulator but not in mobile....